# php discount code error when wrong code entered

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to integrate a discount code into my shopping cart. It works fine, calculates the correct discount when the code is entered, the issue I'm having when the user enters an incorrect code, the cart total just becomes £0.00. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addcoupon").click(function(){
    var ttlamt = $("#ttl_amount").val();
    var ccode = $("#couponcode").val();
    var cpn = ccode.replace(/\s/g, '');
    if(cpn.length <= 0){
        $("#couponcode").css("border-color","red");
    }else{
      $("#couponcode").css("border-color","");
      $.ajax({
          dataType: 'json',
          url: "page.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {action:"coupon_dis",couponval: cpn,amnt: ttlamt},
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
            if(data != "0"){
                $("#grandamount").css("display","none");
                $("#discount_amount").css("display","none");
                $("#couponcode").css("border-color","green");
                $("#grand_discount_amount").css("display","block");
                $("#final_discount_amount").css("display","block");
                $("#grand_discount_amount").html(data.price);
                $("#final_discount_amount").html(data.discount);
            }else{
                $("#discount_amount").css("text-decoration","");
                $("#grandamount").css("text-decoration","");
                $("#couponcode").css("border-color","red");
                $("#grand_discount_amount").css("display","none");
                $("#final_discount_amount").css("display","none");
                $("#grand_discount_amount").html("");
                $("#final_discount_amount").html("");
            }
          }
      });
    }
    return false;
});
```

page.php

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "coupon_dis")
{
   $couponcode = trim($_POST['couponval']);
   $amnt = $_POST['amnt'];
   $val = '0';
   if($couponcode == "loyalty10"){
      $couponDiscount_val = "10";
      $discount_amount = floor($amnt*$couponDiscount_val)/100;
      $amount_after_discount = $amnt - $discount_amount;
      $val = sprintf("%01.2f", $amount_after_discount);
}
   $_SESSION['discount_amount'] = sprintf("%01.2f", $discount_amount);
   $_SESSION['product_discount'] = $val;
}

$return = [
   'price' => $currency.$val, 
   'discount' => $minus.$currency.number_format((float)$discount_amount, 2,'.', '')
];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Tried anything yet?

Comment: Just try to add the original fetched values and populate these in their respective fields in your `else` where you are just changing the border to red.

Comment: See updated script, i did try this earlier but no joy. Seems whatever i add to `else` is not being actioned when the incorrect code is entered.